# Can I give a creature spell hexproof to prevent it from being countered?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The card [Dive Down](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=435205) states:

> Target creature you control gets +0/+3 and gains hexproof until end of turn. (It can't be the target of spells or abilities your opponents control.)

If I cast creature and opponent casts counter, can I Dive Down on the stack to give creature hexproof?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So if I understand correctly:

1. You're casting a creature spell.
2. Your opponent has cast [Essence Scatter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEssence%20Scatter%5d) targeting that spell to counter it.
3. You want to use [Dive Down](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDive%20Down%5d) to prevent that creature spell from being countered.

**No, you can't do this.** For a few reasons:

1. Hexproof only functions on the battlefield. A creature card on the stack that has hexproof can still be a target of your opponent's spells. (Same for when it's in your graveyard, in exile, etc.)

   > 702.11b “Hexproof” on a permanent means “This permanent can’t be the target of spells or abilities your opponents control.”

   (Anytime it's not on the battlefield, it's not a permanent.)
2. Dive Down targets a "creature", which refers to only creature permanents on the battlefield. It can't target a spell — things that target creature spells say "creature spell", such as [Essence Scatter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEssence%20Scatter%5d).

   > **114.2.** Only permanents *[ed: cards and tokens on the battlefield]* are legal targets for spells and abilities, unless a spell or ability (a) specifies that it can target an object in another zone or a player, (b) targets an object that can’t exist on the battlefield, such as a spell or ability, or (c) targets a zone.

If you want to prevent your creatures from getting countered, you'll need effects that say your spell "can't be countered." For example, [Altered Ego](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAltered%20Ego%5d) and [Carnage Tyrant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCarnage%20Tyrant%5d) both can't be countered. Meanwhile [Surrak Dragonclaw](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSurrak%20Dragonclaw%5d) and [Prowling Serpopard](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bProwling%20Serpopard%5d) both grant this ability to other creature spells you cast, whilst also having the ability themselves.

Comment: Thnak you very much for both the answer and suggesting Prowling Serpopard. This was a card I was looking for! The other one unfortunately is not Standard.

Comment: You're welcome. Personally Surrak and Prowling Serpopard are both among my absolute favorite cards, even beside the "your creature spells can't be countered" ability. :)

Comment: I wonder if it'd be worth mentioning the technicality that even if a creature spell can't be countered, it can still be the target of a counterspell like Essence Scatter, it's just that the "counter [the] spell" clause won't do anything. So "can't be countered" is not _quite_ the same as hexproof for spells. It's admittedly obscure but I could imagine that tripping someone up someday.