# Hexproof and "Cannot be countered"

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I play a creature with "cannot be countered" and it has hexproof would either of them make it completely immune during the cast, because as I read something like [Mindbreak trap](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mindbreak%20trap) can remove something with "cannot be countered" because it never resolved, but would there be a way around something like that. I thought hexproof but am not sure

Comment: Just thought of shroud but I think it is in the same boat as hexproof

Comment: Suspect this answers your Q but maybe indirectly/in a round-a-bout way: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/38667/can-i-give-a-creature-spell-hexproof-to-prevent-it-from-being-countered

Answer (score 13):

No, to both ideas.

- The fact that a creature has hexproof has no bearing on the spell the creates the creature; see "[Can I give a creature spell hexproof to prevent it from being countered?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/38667/can-i-give-a-creature-spell-hexproof-to-prevent-it-from-being-countered)".
- A spell which "cannot be countered" stops only effects which say "counter target spell", for example [Counterspell](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Counterspell). It does not stop:

  - The spell being exiled, for example with [Mindbreak Trap](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mindbreak%20Trap)
  - The spell being returned to hand, for example with [Unsubstantiate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Unsubstantiate)
  - The spell being put into its owner's library, for example with [Aether Gust](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Aether%20Gust)
  - The turn ending while the spell is still on the stack, for example with [Discontinuity](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Discontinuity)

Comment: If a spell had the ability "This spell can't be targeted", would it be safe from your first three points?

Comment: @MatthewJensen yes, because all three of those spells target. But I'm not aware of any effects which make spells on the stack untargetable.

Comment: Even if one did exist, that still wouldn't save you from another case of point 1: Summary Dismissal.

Comment: @LizWeir even a Swift Silence or overloaded Counterflux, as they don't target

Comment: My least favorite version of this is Hullbreaker Horror, to just bounce everything from the stack

Answer (score 2):

All the other answers address parts of your question pretty well, but there's one more keyword that hasn't been brought up. If you're looking for a way that a spell can get around the non counter ways of removing it from the stack, the keyword you need is [*split second*](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Split_second).

> **702.61. Split Second**
>
> > **702.61a** Split second is a static ability that functions only while the spell with split second is on the stack. “Split second” means “As long as this spell is on the stack, players can’t cast other spells or activate abilities that aren’t mana abilities.”
> >
> > **702.61b** Players may activate mana abilities and take special actions while a spell with split second is on the stack. Triggered abilities trigger and are put on the stack as normal while a spell with split second is on the stack.
> >
> > **702.61c** Multiple instances of split second on the same spell are redundant.

If a spell (that doesn't target) both says it can't be countered and has split second, I don't believe there is anything in magic that would prevent it from resolving, all the methods of stopping a split second spell generally involve countering triggered abilities like the one on [Kheru Spellsnatcher](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kheru%20Spellsnatcher), which would be stopped by the "can't be countered" part of this theoretical card.

Comment: Is there any way to give spells which don't have it already Split Second?

Comment: Ooooh, good to know about the Kheru Spellsnatcher being able to counter split-second spells, I never noticed. Not that it matters much, but still, good to know. :D

Comment: See also [Willbender](https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/details.aspx?multiverseid=42054) if you're into real shenanigans here. ([Voidmage Apprentice](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393874) and [Silumgar Spell-Eater](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=394704) also counter when turned face-up)

Comment: @PhilipKendall [Molten Disaster](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=376413) gives itself split second if you pay the kicker cost. All other occurrences of "split second" in the text of any card ever printed are simply the static ability on the card. There's nothing that gives it to another spell.

Comment: @fgysin because split second does not interfere with triggered abilities and morph doesn't use the stack, flipping a creature with morph that triggers a counter ability when it is turned face up gets around the split second restrictions.

Comment: @PhilipKendall No, at this point it becomes academic, a card that hard to interact with probably (hopefully) won't ever be printed.

Comment: Note, there are already (3) creatures with split second - and there are existing ways to make your creature spells uncounterable, which covers the fringe cases like morph, so if you come at it from that direction...

Comment: So what we now need is a morph creature that will exile/bounce a spell on the stack upon flipping. :)

Comment: Since we're deep in the hypotheticals here, it would also be removed from the stack if its controller loses the game or concedes. (Are there any morphs that hit face when they turn face-up?)

Comment: @Cadence Atarka Efreet is the only one, deals 1 damage to any target when turned face up.

Answer (score 1):

"Counter" applies to spells on the stack. "Hexproof" applies to permanents on the battlefield. "Counter" has no effect on permanents on the battlefield, and "Hexproof" doesn't apply to spells on the stack. Note that the *card* represents a *spell* while it's on the stack, and represents a *permanent* when it's on the battlefield, making Marc90's use of "card" less precise than "spell" or "permanent". When you cast a spell represented by a particular card, the default is that text on that card applies to the permanent that the spell will become. This default is overridden if the text specifically says it applies in a zone other than the battlefield, or it *can't* apply on the battlefield. For instance, since "counter" only makes sense while the spell is on the stack, it applies on the stack.

In addition, "Hexproof" only stops a permanent from being targeted. So if there were a card that said "Exile *all* spells on the stack", then even if Hexproof applied on the stack, it wouldn't protect from that card, since that doesn't use the word "target". [Sundial of the Infinite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sundial%20of%20the%20Infinite) ends the turns and removes everything from the stack, so it effectively counters everything on the stack, regardless of whether they "can't be countered", and without targeting anything.

Comment: There is a card which is (essentially) "Exile all spells on the stack": [Summary Dismissal](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=414370) (credit to LizWeir for the comment on my answer)